# How do you read in a SQLite table into a dask dataframe?

Tags: python, sqlite, dask

I'm trying to read in a SQLite table into a dask dataframe. I see that there is a function for this, dask.dataframe.read_sql_table()

I am confused on what the index_col parameter does or how it is used. A few examples of how this parameter works would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

index_col refers to how Dask partitions will be made, this means if index_col is a column of categorical variables, say strings then each partition will be a unique value of the strong. If it is a numeric, then partitions are inferred from either bytes_per_chunk or npartitions. Best use case scenario is to supply a string type. Here’s an example where uid is a string:

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as ddf

# ~~ Create sqlite table ~~ #
path_to_db = "c:\\test.db"
conn = sqlite3.connect(path_to_db)
cursor = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test 
            (uid TEXT, 
            col_1 INTEGER''')
c.execute("insert into test values (“A”,2)")
c.execute("insert into test values (“A”,3)”)
c.execute("insert into test values (“A”,4)”)
c.execute("insert into test values (“B”,2)”)
c.execute("insert into test values (“B”,1)”)
conn.commit()

# ~~ Dask query using index_col ~~ #
daskDF = ddf.read_sql_table('test', conn, index_col='uid')
```

Comment: Thanks, what if my table has two columns that together act as the primary key?

Comment: See my edited answer, index_col is how Dask will partition the data. You will have to project multiple columns into one, you can do that before it goes into Dask supplying a sql query to the index_col parameter